# R Shiny : Abline doesn't appear in a boxplot

Tags: r, shiny, boxplot

I'm developing a shiny app where some inputs from the user (which are saved in a dataframe) are used to draw a line across a boxplot with several boxes (using abline).

There was no problem in the first stage of development. It all appeard nicely.

The catch is that, due to the numerous potential boxplots in the app, I ask the user to choose which boxplots it wants to see for a friendlier interface.

Since I've implemented the choosing option, R seems to have trouble with the "abline" command.

In the code below, you can see the two approaches that I've used:

- `abline(h = UserData$X, col = "red")`
  Which led to the following error message:
  `Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  [No stack trace available]` which, sadly, I can't decrypt.
- `abline(h = input$Num_B, col = "red")`
  Which I don't like because it doesn't use the dataframe approved by the user. No message of error here but no line either.

Any ideas for solving this issue?

Thanks a lot and good day to all!

My simplified code for your use:

```
library(shiny)

#UI:
# 1* 2 numeric input from user (Num_A & Num_B) which will be use as a line across the boxplots
# 2* Navbarmenu with 1 tab (for a simpler reading) where the user can chose to display one of 2 boxplots
#    -> The boxplot are there but not the line defined by the input

#Server
# 1* Get the main database file from the computer and order the box plot for further use
# 2* Collect user's inputs in a dataframe
# 3* Construction of the plots

ui <- fluidPage(
############################## 1
  navbarPage(title = "App title",
             tabPanel("User's input tab",
                      titlePanel("Input from user"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel("Fancy sidebar"
                                     ),
                        mainPanel(
                        numericInput("Num_A","1rst user input", value = 1, min=0),
                        numericInput("Num_B","2nd user input", value = 1, min=0),
                        actionButton(inputId = "UserValid",label = "User says go!"),
                        )#end mainpanel
            )#end sidebarlayour
            )#end second tab,
############################## 2
              navbarMenu(title = "Menu tab",
                tabPanel("Graph panel",
                titlePanel("Boxplot"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput("graph", "Choose a graph to view:", 
                                choices = c("Plot1", "Plot2")),
                      actionButton(inputId = "BamUpdate", label = "Update")
                    ),#end sidebarpanel
                  mainPanel(
                    plotOutput("selected_graph")
                    )#end mainpan
                  )#end sidebarlayout BaM
                )#end tabPanel BaM
              )#end navbarMenu
)#end Navbarpage
)#end ui


server <- function(input, output) {
############################## 1
  DB1 <- read.csv2("~/Documents/Cours/Memoire/DT_2.0/ShinyDT/Main/DB1_Comp.csv", row.names = 1, sep=",", dec=".")
  DB1$GRP<-factor(DB1$GRP, levels=c("PmPte+","PmPte-","ItEte+","ItEte-","Tm"))
############################## 2
  UserData <- eventReactive(input$UserValid,{
    data.frame(X=input$Num_A,Y=input$Num_B) 
  })
############################## 3
  plot1 <- eventReactive(input$BamUpdate,{
    boxplot(DB1$SBL~DB1$GRP, main="Plot 1 title", col=c("gray24","green","orangered","blue","saddlebrown"),ylab="Unit",cex.lab=1.2,cex.axis=1.2)
    abline(h = UserData$X, col = "red")
  })
  plot2 <- eventReactive(input$BamUpdate,{
    boxplot(DB1$SSS~DB1$GRP, main="Plot 2 title", col=c("gray24","green","orangered","blue","saddlebrown"),ylab="Unit",cex.lab=1.2,cex.axis=1.2) 
    abline(h = input$Num_B, col = "red")
  })
  graphInput <- eventReactive(input$BamUpdate,{
    switch(input$graph,
           "Plot1" = plot1(),
           "Plot2" = plot2()
    )
  })
  output$selected_graph <- renderPlot({ 
    graphInput()
  })
}#end server


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try `UserData()$X`

Comment: As simple as that!
Thanks a lot!